# React weird behavior when using conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using React 17 with NextJS but I have a weird behavior when trying to switch between two SVG icons.

Here is some code I wrote

```
// I'm using babel-inline-svg plugin
import FlagEn from 'assets/flag_en.svg';
import FlagFr from 'assets/flag_fr.svg';

// some imports and styled components things

const Navigation = ({ isSticky }: NavigationProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
   <nav>
     // other HTML things
     
     <div>
       <Button handleClick={() => setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen)} isTransparent>
         {console.log(isMobileMenuOpen)}  
         {isMobileMenuOpen ? (
           <Close32 fill={isSticky ? Theme.colors.primary : 'white'} />
         ) : (
           <Menu32 fill={isSticky ? Theme.colors.primary : 'white'} />
         )}
       </Button>
     </div>
   </nav>
  )
}
```

As you can see I have a conditional rendering using a simple ternary condition.
You can also see that my nav is sticked to the top when I'm scrolling.

When the nav is sticked everything is working well

[image: menu closed]
[image: menu opened]

But when the nav is not sticked the default menu icon is not hidden

[image: not sticked closed]
[image: not sticked opened]

I tried to change the icons colors because the white background was maybe hidding it, without success.

I also tried:

- to invert the conditional rendering
- change icons
- invert the icon shown when opened/closed
- console log to find if my state is correct

Everything didn't worked.

The only thing I found is that my boolean value saved in the component state is changing everything I scroll down/up

[image: logs]

I really don't understand why the conditional rendering is working ONLY when the nav is sticked.

I also checked if there was any CSS properties that would override the icon color when nav is not sticked, again without success

Did someone already experienced this weird behavior during conditional rending or know why this is happening?

**EDIT**

Here is the `Button` component code:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactElement | string;
  handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler | React.ReactEventHandler;
  color?: string;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  isOutlined?: boolean;
  isTransparent?: boolean;
};

type StyledButtonProps = {
  color: string;
  outlined: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
  transparent: boolean;
};

// Some Styled components things

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  (
    {
      children,
      handleClick,
      color = Theme.colors.primary,
      isDisabled = false,
      isOutlined = false,
      isTransparent = false,
    },
    ref
  ) => (
    <StyledButton
      onClick={handleClick}
      disabled={isDisabled}
      transparent={isTransparent}
      type='button'
      color={color}
      outlined={isOutlined}
      ref={ref}
    >
      {children}
    </StyledButton>
  )
);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking in the DOM or using the React Extensions tools to debug the problem? Seeing the reality in there might be insightful.

Comment: @Chris yes the DOM is correctly changing. In the react devtools extension my state is not shown I don’t know why

Comment: @Jérôme Your Button is a custom component, right? can U share its code as well?

Comment: @blackSheep Icons are from this library https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon/tree/main/packages/icons

Comment: @Jérôme yeah,right, cool but I was asking about the `Button` component itself, the one that gets handleClick function as its prop cuz I wanna know how you handled the props & props.children

Comment: @blackSheep Oh yeah, I've added the code to the original post, sorry for my misreading

Comment: Will it be possible for you to reproduce this on codesandbox? @Jérôme

Comment: @RohitKashyap https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sara-ds33n?file=/src/Button.tsx here is the reproduction

Comment: @Jérôme What exactly is the reproduction in the codesandbox? The conditional rendering seems to be working fine?